# Why Does This Sitemap Fail

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I have tried just about everything I can think of and searched through here to no avail.  Why does this feed seem to not work in Google Webmaster Tools:

https://www.campgroundreviews.com/sitemap

A truncated version of it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://www.campgroundreviews.com/sitemap/users/1</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://www.campgroundreviews.com/sitemap/users/2</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

And a truncated version of an individual sitemap (https://www.campgroundreviews.com/sitemap/cities/13):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.campgroundreviews.com/regions/california/twentynine-palms-marine-corps-ctr</loc>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
        <lastmod>2019-11-27T23:31:14+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.campgroundreviews.com/regions/california/travis-afb</loc>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
        <lastmod>2019-10-24T02:00:58+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.campgroundreviews.com/regions/california/yuba</loc>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
        <lastmod>2019-03-12T11:00:38+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The content-type in the header is being returned as `text/xml; charset=UTF-8`.

In Google Webmaster Tools I get:

[image: Webmaster Tools]

No URLs are ever discovered.  It always says **`Sitemap is HTML`** but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Besides your validity error, which I showed you how to fix and only received your downvote for the effort, you have to make sure that your sitemap isn't being served as HTML.   See duplicate links.

Comment: I have checked all those links.  If you view the links I posted, they are not being served as HTML.  You got a downvote because you answered a question I never asked.

Comment: This is NOT A DUPLICATE POST.  Please READ!

Comment: I'm sorry those links and the validation fixes didn't help.   You should retain the validation fixes anyway, as they'll be useful after you resolve your "Sitemap is HTML" error.  I will reopen your question...

Comment: While you're waiting for a definitive answer, you might try removing the XSLT processing instruction: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/sitemap.xsl"?>`  This should be fine, but sometimes pruning down to a [mcve] can reveal  surprises.  In this case, if Google's agent is running the XSLT prior to parsing the XML, then the result of the XSLT transformation will be HTML, which could account for your "Sitemap is HTML".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, this was NOT an issue with the sitemap itself.  We were using prerender as per Google's recommendation ( https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering ), but I forgot to blacklist the sitemap URLs, so Webmaster Tools was viewing the maps via prerender.io instead of directly from the server.

Hopefully this helps somebody else out in the future.